# Expressing an equation in terms of its generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, polynomials, partial-differential-equations, symbolic-computation

I have a generating set of differential equations:
$$ I_1=u_t\\
I_2=-uu_{tt}\\
I_3=u^{-1}\\
I_4=uu_{xxx}-6u^2u_x $$
where $u=u(x,t)$. and the coordinate is $(x,t,u,u_x,u_t,u_{tt},u_{xxx})$. Infact we assume partitial derivatives of $u(x,t)$ as dependent variables. Therefore, the differential equations become algebraic polynomials. We can regard the set as a Gröbner basis.

I know that the above equations generate the equation
$$ u_t+u_{xxx}-6uu_x=0 $$

I want to express eq2 as a function relation of the generating set. which is
$$ I_1+I_3I_4=0 $$

I want to know how could I express an equation in terms of generators?

Is there any method or computer package to solve my problem?

Comment: Why the abstract-algebra and differential-geometry tags?